# Find reference using the field name using Rally Java rest api

Tags: java, rest, rally

Is there any methods available in Rally to find the field needs a reference value or not. For eg, i'll get Owner,TestFolder, priority, severity. Out of these fields first 2 needs a reference string to create a test case. How to find the fields have to be a reference field or it can be as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the web service docs here:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Things like Owner and TestFolder will describe the One to One relationship.  The other two fields have an explicit list of allowed values.

You can also get all this dynamically through the WSAPI:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/typedefinition?query=(TypePath%20=%20Defect)&fetch=Attributes will give you the ref to the attributes collection.

Then you can get the contents of the attributes like this:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TypeDefinition/41529147/Attributes

Things like Owner will have an "AttributeType": "OBJECT"
Things like Priority will have an "AttributeType": "RATING"